# NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>' method not found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to build a web app on Flutter. I was trying to add in some code for some buttons I found online but I'm getting this error and I have no idea why. The code seems to have no errors in itself, but when I run the program I get this error.

```
NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>' method not found
```

The program is basically looks like an app bar: it shows a bunch of rectangular buttons that include Settings, Log out, etc. Before this, I successfully built the backdrop and a rectangle for the buttons to go placed. The buttons themselves are causing this error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import '../time/time_view.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../../app/constants/strings.dart';
import '../../../app/services/firebase_auth_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_firebase_googe_auth/size_config.dart';

String name = '';
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
getCurrentUserName() async {
  final user = await _auth.currentUser();
  if (user.isAnonymous) {
    name = 'Guest';
  } else {
    name = user.displayName;
  }
}

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeView({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // variable size
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    getCurrentUserName();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                elevation: 5.0,
                child: Container(
                  width: size.width,
                  height: size.height * .9,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: Text(
                          '\t\tHome Page \n Welcome',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      SpecialOffers(),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TimeView()),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text(Strings.time),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          context.read<FirebaseAuthService>().signOut();
                        },
                        child: const Text(Strings.signOut),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SectionTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const SectionTitle({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final GestureTapCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(18),
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: press,
          child: Text(
            "See More",
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFBBBBBB)),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SpecialOffers extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpecialOffers({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
          child: SectionTitle(
            title: "Special for you",
            press: () {},
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SpecialOfferCard(
                image: "assets/images/Image Banner 2.png",
                category: "Smartphone",
                numOfBrands: 18,
                press: () {},
              ),
              SpecialOfferCard(
                image: "assets/images/Image Banner 3.png",
                category: "Fashion",
                numOfBrands: 24,
                press: () {},
              ),
              SizedBox(width: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SpecialOfferCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpecialOfferCard({
    Key key,
    @required this.category,
    @required this.image,
    @required this.numOfBrands,
    @required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String category, image;
  final int numOfBrands;
  final GestureTapCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: press,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: getProportionateScreenWidth(242),
          height: getProportionateScreenWidth(100),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  image,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        Color(0xFF343434).withOpacity(0.4),
                        Color(0xFF343434).withOpacity(0.15),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(15.0),
                    vertical: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                  ),
                  child: Text.rich(
                    TextSpan(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                          text: "$category\n",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(18),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(text: "$numOfBrands Brands")
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this error when running `myVariable++` when it was null: `int myVariable;`. Maybe you can find this kind of thing in your code...

Comment: Are you sure that this row `final user = await _auth.currentUser();` does not return `null`? If `null` is returned then this row `if (user.isAnonymous)` will throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` should usually point which line causes the issue. This should be found somewhere in the complete set of logs.

From the code, one of the likely cause for this error is `FirebaseAuth _auth`. You may also want to check if FirebaseAuth isn't being null on your Provider `context.read<FirebaseAuthService>().signOut();`.